# Plots in tikz get jagged, should be smooth instead

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I tried to plot a function using tikz. It does however look aweful when I change one parameter slightly (see in the code below). The funciton is just a polynomial of degree 6. What am I doing wrong?

The parameter that can be changed is `\s`. If it is at `0.8` I get an error `Dimension too large!` that I also do not understand.

The first picture is with the parameter `\s` at `0.75`. The second picture is at `0.65`, way smoother, but still quite bad.

[image] [image]

(The reason for this parameter is that in the end, I want to plot that function for different values of that parameter.)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1,scale=3]
\def \d {3};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0); %axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[color=black,domain=0:1] plot[samples=100](\x,{\x});
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{0.75}; %the closer to 0.8, the worse (smaller = better)
\draw[color=black,domain=\s:1] plot[samples=100](\x,{\x*pow(\x-(2*\s-1),\d)*pow(\x-1,\d)/(pow(1-\s,\d)*pow(\s-1,\d))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that when s tends to 1 the gradient of the curve gets high hence you should increase the number of samples to make the curve smoother. The "dimension is too large" because the curve gets out of the article or paper size you entered as an option of your documentclass.

Comment: I tried increasing the number of  samples. For `\s` at `0.75` it first (at 1000 samples) doesn't get any less jagged, and then (10000 samples) becomes just a straight line. Also I still can't get much above `0.75` even with an increased number of samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `fpu` library to get higher precision.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1,scale=3,
  /pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed  % activate fpu for tikzpicture
  ]
\def \d {3};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0); %axis
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[color=black,domain=0:1] plot[samples=100](\x,{\x});
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{0.75}; %the closer to 0.8, the worse (smaller = better)
\draw[color=black,domain=\s:1] plot[samples=100](\x,{\x*pow(\x-(2*\s-1),\d)*pow(\x-1,\d)/(pow(1-\s,\d)*pow(\s-1,\d))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial answer: It seems to be a numerical issue. tikz seems to have a very low precision arithmetic. Rearranging the terms in the polynomial to increase the stability of the expression resulted in much smoother curves. Basically I changed expressions like `a^d / b^d`  to `(a/b)^d` .

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{0.8};
\draw[color=black,domain=\s:1] plot[samples=100](\x,{\x*pow((\x-(2*\s-1))/(1-\s),\d)*pow((\x-1)/(\s-1),\d)});
```